# "No unmounted partitions found" error while restoring Clonezilla backup to VirtualBox VM

Tags: virtualbox, clonezilla

I have an old notebook on which I would like to reinstall XP.

I thought I could create an image with Clonezilla (which I did successfully, stored the image to my USB-Drive) and create a VirtualBox virtual machine and load that image into it, so that I can "use" my old notebook's XP in that virtual computer.

So, I boot the VirtualBox with the Clonezilla Live CD. But when Clonezilla runs, at some point it complains:

> "Error! No unmounted partitions found..."

I have no idea what this error could mean.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a virtual hard disk attached to the Virtual Machine you are trying to restore to? This sounds to me you only have the Clonezilla image mounted in the Virtual Machine. Also USB filters do work a bit funny (ok, I've never had any luck and prefer to use shared folders instead).

What I would do is:

- Add a virtual hard disk to your virtual machine the same size as your XP HD.
- Add *another* virtual hard disk to the computer and copy the image across to the second hard disk.
- Use clonezilla to restore the image (from being stored on the second disk) to the primary disk

After that you'll probably need to tweak a few things to get your virtual XP install working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually mount my USB drive in VirtualBox using the menu.

> Device → USB → check my USB drive